# Site not loading properly in IE 8 for first few seconds

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, iis

I am using ASP.NET 3.5 and we are having a problem with our website [www.s1.com](http://www.s1.com)

Also go to other links in the page if you dont see it on the home page.

When you open the site in IE 8 the top menu at first gets displayed like this.
[image]
<sub>(source: [erate.co.za](http://www.erate.co.za/error.jpg))</sub>

And then the rest of the website loads. What can this be? Maybe a setting on the Server or in IIS?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, I just opened the site in IE8 and it loaded fine first time.

Comment: Please open more link in the site such as this one please. http://www.s1.com/Solutions/atm_driving.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem, because i was using masterpages the CSS reference was on the child page and needed to go onto the masterpage above everything else.

Comment: You can solve this issue by adding a asp:ContentPlaceholder in the <head> of the masterpage - this allows you to add page specific CSS in the correct place in the markup.

Answer (score 1):

This is a result of the formatting of the inline ordered list not completed before the display. Can be very dependent on cache, client browser, network etc.

Css/javascript files loaded later than the page content body is a common cause of this. But usually is not 'critical'.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it is because the JS that hides the menu is executed after everything else has loaded, therefore, until then, the menu is visible.
Hide the menu via CSS then show it in the JS function that works with the menu.

Comment: It's not the JavaScript - if you switch JavaScript off entirely it doesn't leave sections visible. It's down to the CSS not being loaded before that list is rendered - if you inspect the web traffic, the CSS files (which are very small) sometimes have to queue behind a couple of the images - even though everything is small and downloads quickly, queuing time is longer than download time - it very rarely happened in my test as I have a fast connection but the result would be amplified on a slower connection.

Comment: @Sohnee: you should have answered instead of commenting +1 :)